# TypeError: is not a function typescript class

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I'm getting the following error in my typescript class and cannot understand why. All I am doing is trying to call a helper function passing the token.

Error:

> post error:  TypeError: this.storeToken is not a function(…)

Class:

```js
/**
 * Authentication Service:
 *
 * Contains the http request logic to authenticate the
 * user.
 */
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response, Headers, RequestOptions } from '@angular/http';

import 'rxjs/Rx';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

import { AuthToken } from './auth-token.service';

import { User } from '../../shared/models/user.model';

@Injectable()
export class Authenticate {

  constructor(
    private http: Http,
    private authToken: AuthToken
  ) {}

  post(user: User): Observable<any> {
    let url = 'http://localhost:4000/';
    let body = JSON.stringify(user);
    let headers = new Headers({ 'content-type': 'application/json' });
    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });

    return this.http.post(url + 'login', body, options)
      .map(this.handleData)
      .catch(this.handleError);
  }

  private storeToken(token: string) {
    this.authToken.setToken(token);
  }

  private handleData(res: Response) {
    let body = res.json();
    this.storeToken(body.token);
    return body.fields || {};
  }

  private handleError(error: any) {
    console.error('post error: ', error);
    return Observable.throw(error.statusText);
  }
}
```

I am new to typescript so I'm sure I am missing something ridiculously simple. Any assist would be great.

Thanks.

Comment: I think this response would help
https://stackoverflow.com/a/60789956/6109900

Answer (score 21, accepted):

It should either be (using [Function.prototype.bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind)):

```
return this.http.post(url + 'login', body, options)
      .map(this.handleData.bind(this))
      .catch(this.handleError.bind(this));
```

Or (using [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)):

```
return this.http.post(url + 'login', body, options)
      .map((res) => this.handleData(res))
      .catch((error) => this.handleError(error));
```

What happens is that you are passing a reference to your method but it's not bound to a specific `this`, so when the method is executed the `this` in the function body isn't the instance of the class but the scope that executes the method.

Each of of those help keep the right context for `this`, but in a different way.

---

#### Edit

Another option is:

```
export class Authenticate {
    ...

    private handleData = (res: Response) => {
        ...
    }

    private handleError = (error: any) => {
        ...
    }
}
```

In this way the "methods" are already bound, **but** in this case they won't be part of the prototype, and will in fact become just properties of type function.
For example:

```
class A {
    method1() { }
    method2 = () => {}
}
```

Compiles to:

```
// es5
var A = (function () {
    function A() {
        this.method2 = function () { };
    }
    A.prototype.method1 = function () { };
    return A;
}());

// es6
class A {
    constructor() {
        this.method2 = () => { };
    }
    method1() { }
}
```

Because of that `method2` can't be (easily) overriden, so beware of this implementation.

Comment: Sure thing. I edited my answer with another approach, which I'm not a fan of, but it's still an option.

Comment: I feel the arrow functions are the way to go since it is a consistent pattern. I was experimenting with some different patterns I found online and forgot to convert those to the arrow function which is why I had the issue and didn't realize what happened.